# Why are integral group rings so important in topology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, group-rings

Having worked on group rings $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ for the last year, I am beginning to feel quite comfortable with them. I also know of a few applications to topology. However, these are individual uses whereas integral group rings seem to be fundamental in some sense in algebraic topology (they keep cropping up!). So I was wondering what makes them so crucial? What is it about them that makes them more important than, say, $R[G]$ ($R$ commutative). Is this also a feature shared in geometry, i.e. is $\mathbb{Z}$ just as important in the realms of algebraic geometry?

Comment: Categorically, $G\to\mathbb Z[G]$ is the adjoint of the functor $U$ from $\mathrm{Ring}$ to $\mathrm{Group}$ by sending a ring $R$ to its group of units. Then $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Group}}(G,U(R))\cong \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Ring}}(\mathbb Z[G],R)$. The general case $R[G]$ is odder: it is an adjoint, but from the category of $R$-rings (rings $S$ with a homomorphism $R\to S$.) So, in some "deep" sense, $\mathbb Z[G]$ is the most basic (and the others are just $R[G]=R\otimes Z[G]$.) That doesn't mean $R[G]$ is never interesting, but it might imply that we want to start with $\mathbb Z[G]$.

Comment: (Not sure if that comment specifically applies to topology, just a general note about the centrality of $\mathbb Z[G]$.)

Comment: @Thomas The better term is R-algebras, and in general, if you're interested in R-algebras or group actions on R-modules you're interested in R[G].

Comment: Yeah, I've seen some places that use $R$-algebra to include sometimes non-associative algebras, or algebras without identites, so I wanted to be specific. @MikeMiller

Comment: I hazard a guess that you see these often because if a group $G$ acts on a topological space, then it also acts on its (co)homology groups. If you work with coefficients $\Bbb{Z}$, then you can turn those (co)homology groups into $\Bbb{Z}[G]$-modules. For $R[G]$ to show up you need coefficients in $R$, but IIRC (it's over 25 years since grad school) integer coefficients are more common. In a number theoretical context $\Bbb{Z}[G]$ is the only thing we have when $G$ is acting on the *multiplicative* group of a number field $K$, and raising to a fractional power will take us outside of $K$.

Comment: @Jyrki Those are good examples, though frequently one might want to take a ring other than $R$ because the resulting cohomology ring structure is better behaved. (Think $\Bbb Z/2$ for real projective space.)